# Strange 404 use urllib or requests to access flask or SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, http, urllib, simplehttpserver

I'm trying python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package, I start an example using [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) with a file '/about' at root, surprisingly, requests.get('localhost:8000/about') got 404 for that.

And then I used [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)'s run(), and it's also 404, and then I switch requests to [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), and guess what, 404.

But other tools can get 200 response, from both flask and SimpleHTTPServer, I've tried curl, siege, firefox and wget, all of these works.

On the other side, when I switch SimpleHTTPServer to [nginx](http://nginx.org/), or hide flask behind [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), both requests and urllib get 200.

And I know the difference of the request from access log: when using requests and urllib, access log got:

```
"GET http://localhost:8000/about HTTP/1.1"
```

but when using curl, access log got

```
"GET /about HTTP/1.1"
```

So I still don't know what I'm dealing with (and what's the reason behind it) and what can I expect to avoid such error.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

It turned out that this is not true in all machines, I do have another machine that suffer none problems at all